# how to check property type is string in ef 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi I am trying to set user id column in changed entities if entity has a 'UserID' column and the column type is String. I am able to check 'UserID' existence with following code but have no idea how to confirm its type is String. Can you please help?

```
List<DbEntityEntry> modifiedChanges = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x =>
                    x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified)
                    .ToList();

foreach (var change in modifiedChanges)
{
    if (change.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.Contains("UserID"))
    {
        /* TODO: How to check property type is string? */
        change.Property("UserID").CurrentValue = userID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can "UserID" be null? If not, you can simply check if the current value is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<DbEntityEntry> modifiedChanges = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x =>
                    x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified)
                    .ToList();

foreach (var change in modifiedChanges)
{
    if (change.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.Contains("UserID"))
    {
        if (change.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("UserID").PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
           change.Property("UserID").CurrentValue = userID;
        }
    }
}
```